# modprobe FATAL: Module XXX.ko not found

Tags: linux

I searched via google and here on the side. But no solution appears.

I have a module XXX.ko . It works fine with insmod. Than I copied it to `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` But it still don't work with modprobe

What's the solution?

I also run `depmod XXX.ko`

Comment: What's the output of `depmod -a`?

Comment: Please add the _exact_ commands you have tried, including _the real names_ for all files involved. It is hard to guess what you actually have tried.